# "node-pre-gyp: not found" when compiling canvas with Yarn 1

Tags: node.js, next.js, yarnpkg, node-gyp

I changed the path to my Next.js application on my VPS server, and now my dependencies aren't installing correctly with Yarn. (I'm on Yarn 1, not Yarn 2.)

Yarn crashes trying to build the native code for the npm module `canvas`, saying: `node-pre-gyp: not found`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the new path to the application had a colon `:` in one of the folder names. (The folder was named with an ISO timestamp, like `2021-11-03T02:02:44`, to represent when this version of the app was built.)

Colons are a special character for looking up executables in most systems: the `PATH` variable is usually split by colons.

I suspect that Yarn 1 has a bug where it inserts the folder name into the `PATH` without escaping any colons, which causes `PATH` to parse incorrectly. This causes the system to look in two incorrect folder names, instead of the one correct folder name, for the executables like `node-pre-gyp` that it needs to build special native-code dependencies like `canvas`.

To fix this, stop using colons in your folder names that contain Node applications where you depend on Yarn 1 for compiling native code. Rename the folder to something else.